# What are the rounding rules of Java Explicit Cast from Double to Int

Tags: java, casting, integer, double

Ran into a weird quirk when demonistrating Java explicit type casting today and was wondering why this happens.

If I convert a double into an int, and my number is .9 up to 16 precision, it will round up. (See comments in code) If I make it 15 precision it rounds down.

Similarly, if I make my number .8... it will still round down.

```
        double a = 5.9999999999999999;// 16 precision rounds to 6
        double a1 = 5.8888888888888888; // 16 precision rounds to 5
        double b = 5.999999999999999;// 15 precision rounds to 5
        double c = 5.111111111111111111111111111111111111111; //rounds to 5
        int cast = (int)a;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000000 ; i++){
            System.out.print(cast);
        }
```

Initially thought I was overflowing the int, but it doesn't appear that is the case.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you print `cast` so many times? Do you expect it to change?

Comment: Use the _[BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html)_ class.

Comment: None of these values is exact in the first place.

Comment: @AndyTurner I mean, no, but Then I thought maybe it was a weird compile error so I better print it lots of times to make sure I get consistent results.

Comment: @user207421 I understand that, was just giving examples of casting and ran into that and have never run into that before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting conversions that involve a narrowing primitive conversion from a floating point type to an integral type will round to zero, according to the [JLS Section 5.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3):

> A narrowing conversion of a floating-point number to an integral type T takes two steps:
>
> 1. In the first step, the floating-point number is converted either to a long, if T is long, or to an int, if T is byte, short, char, or int, as follows:
>
> - If the floating-point number is NaN (§4.2.3), the result of the first step of the conversion is an int or long 0.
> - Otherwise, if the floating-point number is not an infinity, the floating-point value is rounded to an integer value V using the round toward zero rounding policy (§4.2.4).

So why does `double a = 5.9999999999999999;` seemingly round up?  The `double` literal has to be converted to a `double` value first.  This is covered by the Floating-Point Literals section of the [JLS (3.10.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2):

> *The details of proper input conversion from a Unicode string representation of a floating-point number to the internal IEEE 754 binary floating-point representation are described for the methods valueOf of class Float and class Double of the package java.lang.*

Ok, let's go to [`valueOf` for `Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)):

> [The string value] is regarded as representing an exact decimal value in the usual "computerized scientific notation" or as an exact hexadecimal value; this exact numerical value is then conceptually converted to an "infinitely precise" binary value that is then rounded to type `double` by the usual **round-to-nearest rule** of IEEE 754 floating-point arithmetic, which includes preserving the sign of a zero value.

<sub>(bold emphasis mine)</sub>

At 16 digits of precision beyond the decimal point (you have 17 include `5`), you are pushing the limits of precision for a `double` literal.  At this point, `5.9999999999999999` is closer to `6` than the next lower `double` value.

So, 6 is displayed because your floating point literal gets rounded *up* to `6.0` as a `double` *before* it gets cast to an `int`, and `6.0` cast to an `int` is the 6 you see printed.

Other values you have don't get rounded all the way up to `6.0` as `double` literals, so the cast to `int` brings it all the way down to 5.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with casting to `int`.

If you print the value of `a`:

```
double a = 5.9999999999999999;
System.out.println(a);
```

It prints `6.0`.

This is because double has finite precision, and cannot represent the literal value exactly.